# Guice DI in Callable

Tags: java, guice

I have a specific question wrt to usage of Guice in Parallel Environment.

I have a runnable which takes constrcutor argument.

```
class task implements Runnable{
String dbname="";
task(String dbname)
{
this.dbname=dbname
}
@
Inject
private ICacheService cacheService
public void run(){
//logic here

}
bind(ICacheService).to(CacheServiceImpl.class);


}
```

Question:How do I instantiate Task.

I cannot use ExecutorService.submit(new as this will not be right way and defies purpose of guice.)

Comment: Is dbname varying per each Runnable instance? I'd suggest you inject ICacheService using constructor injection and use Builder pattern to initialize other properties. Also, you can register your Task class with hk2-di module and request new instances of Task (or probably TaskBuilder) from ServiceLocator.

Comment: Yes it is.I have found solution.Core of Problem was to figure out how to submittasks without usins new and pass the arugment to Runnable Constructor

Answer (score 1):

I would create a factory which creates task, inject ICacheService via constructor in task and make use of `javax.inject.Provider`

```
public class TaskFactory {

    private Provider<ICacheService> cacheServiceProvider;

    @Inject
    public TaskFactory(Provider<ICacheService> cacheServiceProvider) {
        this.cacheServiceProvider = cacheServiceProvider;
    }

    public task create(String dbname) {
        return new task(dbname, cacheServiceProvider.get());
    }
}


class task implements Runnable {

    private final String dbname;
    private final ICacheService cacheService;

    public task(String dbname, ICacheService cacheService) {
        this.dbname = dbname;
        this.cacheService = cacheService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Once I have done this, I will inject TaskFactory and then call the create method with dbName.

You can also use [AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) from Guice to do similar stuff.

BTW, class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: I checked online and found ur approach convinncing

Answer (score 0):

After little bit of googling I found the solution.
Binding:

```
public class DependecnyBinderModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(CloudSync.class).to(AWSCloudSyncImpl.class);

        bind(IConfigurationPropertyInitializer.class).to(ConfigurationPropertyInitializerImpl.class);

        bind(ICloudClientProvider.class).to(CloudClientProvider.class);

        bind(IQueryConnection.class).to(QueryConnectionImpl.class);

        bind(IWorkSpaceDescriptorInitialization.class).to(WorkSpaceDescriptorInitialize.class);
        bind(ISubscribeQueue.class).to(SubScribeQueueImpl.class);

        bind(InitializeDataSource.class).to(InitializeDataSourceImpl.class);

        bind(InitiateQueueListening.class).to(InitiateQueueListeningImpl.class);

        bind(DataExtractor.class).to(DataExtractorImpl.class);

        bind(DataTransformer.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
        bind(TaskDispatcher.class);
        **install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(Runnable.class, MultiQueueConsumer.class).build(TaskCreatorFactory.class));**

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ThreadFactory providesThreadFactory() {
        return new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setDaemon(true).setNameFormat("RealTimeSync-%d")
                .setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new RealTimeSyncExceptionHandler()).build();
    }



}
```

Your Task Dispatcher to dispatch tasks to Executor.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

import com.google.inject.Inject;

/**
 * @author marwaha
 *
 */
public class TaskDispatcher {
@Inject
private ThreadFactory factory;

@Inject

private RuunableFactory factory2;
    private ExecutorService executor;

    public void dispatch(String name) {
        if(executor==null) {
            executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, factory);
        }
        executor.submit(factory2.create(name));

    }

}
```

RunnableFactory

```
public interface RuunableFactory {

    Task create(String dbname);
}
```